# Best way to implement partitioning when date desired but no date column

Tags: sql, partitioning, database-indexes

I have my own idea on how to handle this, but want to see if there is a different perspective on this. The problem I have with this is I have the following tables (sample tables)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE Account
(
    AccountId int identity(1,1),
    CreationDate datetime,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Account] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [AccountId] ASC
    )WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE AccountSales
(
    AccountSalesId int identity(1,1),
    AccountId int,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AccountSales] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
       [AccountSalesId] ASC
    )WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AccountSales]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AccountSales_Account]    FOREIGN KEY([AccountId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Account] ([AccountID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AccountSales] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AccountSales_Account]
GO
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Let's say the Account table is 500GB and the AccountSales is 1TB. I would like to partition these tables for obvious reasons. The way the current logic works is that data is dealt with on a day by day basis, so it makes sense to partition on the date field for the Account table, however the AccountSales table has no date field. Also the data in both tables is no sequential when it comes to the id and date as data is loaded from different servers at different times. So like accounts may have the following data

```
Id     Date             Server loaded from (not a column - just for display purposes)
--------------------------
1      1/1/2000 00:00     1
2      1/1/2000 01:00     1
3      1/1/2000 02:00     1
4      1/1/2000 00:00     2
5      1/1/2000 01:00     2
6      1/1/2000 0:300     1
```

I was thinking about for the Accounts table just making the clustered index on CreationDate and setting the AccountId as a PK with Unique NC index. I would then partition on the date.

I'm not 100% sure of how to handle the AccountSales table though - since if I did it by id the dates would not match up correctly if joined with the Account table, however I don't see a way to fix this.

Any ideas? What is the best way to handle this? If any more information is needed please let me know. Thanks if advance!

Comment: Can you say what you will be using partitioning for? Will you switch partitions? What else will you do?

Comment: Yes, I'll be switching and merging partitions - basically I'm doing the partitions similar to the archiving logic we have.  I'm employing a sliding window technique to accomplish this, where (among the other partitions) after 90 days I'll be splitting the partitions and (potentially) switching them after that.  Merging is done on partitions at the very front of the table though.

Answer (score 0):

You said in the comments that you aim to use partitioning metadata-only operations in order to bulk-update data. This means that you need to partition both tables because you surely want to keep them in sync. Also, you need to partition-align them so that you are able to switch or drop both in the same (fast) transaction.

For that reason, I recommend that you include the partitioning key in both tables. Even though it is redundant in one of them.